# Setting up Sentry in an Elixir app, getting undefined function String.trim/2

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework, sentry

I'm following these instructions (https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-elixir) to set up Sentry error notifications in an Elixir/Phoenix app.  It works fine in my dev environment, but when I push to production (using Heroku) I get the following error which seems to occur within the Sentry module itself:  `(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function String.trim/2`.

Here is the full log output:

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741733+00:00 app[web.1]:     ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function String.trim/2
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741736+00:00 app[web.1]:         (elixir) String.trim("** (Phoenix.ActionClauseError) bad request to MyApp.UserController.create, no matching action clause to process request", "*")
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741737+00:00 app[web.1]:         (sentry) lib/sentry/event.ex:65: Sentry.Event.transform_exception/2
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741738+00:00 app[web.1]:         (sentry) lib/sentry.ex:86: Sentry.capture_exception/2
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741739+00:00 app[web.1]:         (plug) lib/plug/error_handler.ex:96: Plug.ErrorHandler.__catch__/5
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741740+00:00 app[web.1]:         (my_app) lib/my_app/endpoint.ex:1: MyApp.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741741+00:00 app[web.1]:         (my_app) lib/my_app/endpoint.ex:1: MyApp.Endpoint.call/2
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741742+00:00 app[web.1]:         (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
2016-12-01T23:14:00.741742+00:00 app[web.1]:         (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

and when I try to access `alias String` by logging into the `iex` via `heroku run`, I get `nil`.

Any idea why the `String` module is undefined in production only?

Comment: setting 
`erlang_version=19.0` and
`elixir_version=1.3.4`

in `elixir_buildpack.config` solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

i think you need to force heroku to use elixir version 1.3.x
If you use the heroku-buildpack-elixir set your elixir version to minimum of 1.3.0

> https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir

There is the corresponding issue:

> https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-elixir/issues/95